# Regenerate help tags automatically on save (Windows)

Tags: vim

I am using gVim 8.2 on Windows 10.

I have prepared a personnal help file (lets say `myHelp.txt`) and stored in under `C:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Vim\vim82\doc`. When I update the file and change/add tags, I am able to regenerate them by running:

```
:helptags C:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Vim\vim82\doc
```

I wanted to run this automatically everything I made a change to my help file, so I added this to my `.vimrc` (stolen from [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Add_your_note_files_to_Vim_help)):

```
autocmd BufWritePost C:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Vim\vim82\doc\* :helptags C:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Vim\vim82\doc
```

It basically says: "whenever a file under `C:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Vim\vim82\doc\` is saved, run `:helptags C:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Vim\vim82\doc` when writing is completed". However, when I save my help file, tags are not updated. I see no error, nothing.

I suspect there might be a problem with the way my paths are interpreted, and I have tried:

1. Changing backslashed to forwarslashes
2. using `shellescape` (`shellescape('C:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Vim\vim82\doc')`)

but nothing works (again, no error, nothing).

How could I make this work?

Comment: Don't mess with Vim standard dirs. Create a plugin if you need it.

Comment: Also prefer slashes over backslashes even on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
C:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Vim\vim82\
```

is off-limits. Whatever you do to customise Vim should happen in:

```
C:\Users\BobMorane\vimfiles\
```

In this case, your file should be there:

```
C:\Users\BobMorane\vimfiles\doc\myHelp.txt
```

and your autocommand should look like this:

```
autocmd BufWritePost ~/vimfiles/doc/* :helptags ~/vimfiles/doc/
```

You can use UNIX conventions within Vim: `~` is always the user's "home" directory and `/` can be used no matter what platform you are on.

Comment: Very clear answer, thanks! Regarding the autocommand, the current form (with `<afile>`) doesn't seem to be working. I get the following error: `E150: Not a directory: vimfiles\doc\myHelp.txt`. To get it working properly, I had to change it to `autocmd BufWritePost ~/vimfiles/doc/* :helptags ~/vimfiles/doc`.

Comment: It is also weird that I was able to update tags manually for an "off-limit" location...

Comment: Oh right, `:helptags` takes a directory, not a file. As for the off-limit stuff, think of it as having an affair with your best friend's mom: it is neither against the law nor physically impossible and it can even be quite cool, but it's risky business.